# ef core one-to-one property is always null

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to define (using data annotations, that's the project pattern, not using the fluent api) a one-to-one relationship but the navigation property (`public virtual HolidayType HolidayType`) is always null. The db table is creating the ForeignKey correctly using the annotation `[ForeignKey("HolidayTypeId")]`.

### Holiday Model

```
[Table("Holidays", Schema = "PTO")]
public class Holiday : EntityBase
{
    ...
    public long HolidayTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HolidayTypeId")]
    public virtual HolidayType HolidayType { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

### db FK constraint

```
ALTER TABLE [PTO].[Holidays]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT  [FK_Holidays_HolidayTypes_HolidayTypeId] FOREIGN KEY([HolidayTypeId])
 REFERENCES [PTO].[HolidayTypes] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

### Holiday Types Table

```
[Table("HolidayTypes", Schema = "PTO")]
public class HolidayType : EntityBase
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

### EntityBase

```
public class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedByGuidId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Guid UpdatedByGuidId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the repository call, the holidays are retrieved but they are missing the `HolidayType` property - always null. My understanding, using the ForeignKey annotation, the query does not need to have an `.include` statement. My understanding is obviously flawed so my next step is to try the include statement to verify. I'm hoping that an `include` statement doesn't require an addition db call if that is the answer to my issue.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await ApplicationDbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I figured it out and posted an answer below for any in a similar situation but I'm not sure it's the best solution so I'm glad to receive feedback for improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `.Include` statement is needed but it breaks my repository implementation so I need to rethink that.

This now hydrates the HolidayType:

```
    public async Task<List<Holiday>> GetHolidaysByEmployerId(long employerId, int? year = null)
    {
        Expression<Func<Holiday, bool>> predicate = holiday => holiday.EmployerId == employerId;
        var result = await ApplicationDbContext.Set<Holiday>().Where(predicate)
                            .Include(holiday => holiday.HolidayType)
                            .ToListAsync();
        return result.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: This is due to the way that EF Core hydrates navigation properties: in that it doesn't unless you explicitly tell it to. The reason given for this is that most devs who relied on it in EF 6 ended up relying on code which generated inefficient SQL; so the designers of EF Core decided to leave auto hydration of navigation properties off by default